# Nothing is rendering in DX 11

Tags: c++, directx-11

Nothing is rendering in my DX program in C++(using PS_5_0 and VS_5_0).I have check all of the DX functions that return an HRESULT and they all return S_OK, I Have also gone through and carefully debugged and looked at everything and nothing is null or uninitialized. I even searched every where here and on bing and I did not find any post that helped me(tried all of there solutions to see if they worked, none of them did).I have no idea why it is not rendering, all of the parameters are good.

Here is my code the initializes the Depth stencil, Device context and Device.

```
    //create the graphics device factory
    result = CreateDXGIFactory(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), (void**)&factory);

    //use the factor to create the adapter for the primary graphics interface(video card)
    result = factory->EnumAdapters(0, &adapter);
    if (FAILED(result))
        return false;

    //enumerate the primary adapter output(monitor)
    result = adapter->EnumOutputs(0, &adapterOutput);
    if (FAILED(result))
        return false;

    //get the adapter(video card) description
    result = adapter->GetDesc(&adapterDesc);
    if (FAILED(result))
        return false;

    //zero out the swap chain description
    ZeroMemory(&swapChainDesc, sizeof(swapChainDesc));

    //Set ot to a single back buffer
    swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 1;

    //set regular 32 bit surface for the back buffer.
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;

    //set the usage of the back buffer.
    swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;

    //set the handle for the window to render to.
    swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = hwnd;

    //turn multi sampling off
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;

    //set the scan line odering and scaling to unspecified.
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;

    //discard the back buffer contents after presenting
    swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;

    //donw set the advanced flags
    swapChainDesc.Flags = 0;

    //set the feature level to directX 11
    featureLevel = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0;

    //create the swap chain,Direct3D, and the driect3D device context.
    result = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, 0, &featureLevel, 1,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc, &m_swapChain, &m_device, NULL, &m_deviceContext);
    if (FAILED(result))
        return false;

    //Get the pointer to the back buffer
    result = m_swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&backBufferPtr);
    if (FAILED(result))
        return false;

    //create the render target view with the back buffer pointer
    result = m_device->CreateRenderTargetView(backBufferPtr, NULL, &m_renderTarget);

    //set up the description of the depth buffer
    depthBufferDesc.Width = screenWidth;
    depthBufferDesc.Height = screenHeight;
    depthBufferDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    depthBufferDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    depthBufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    depthBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    depthBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
    depthBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    depthBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    //Create the texture for the depth buffer using the filled out description
    result = m_device->CreateTexture2D(&depthBufferDesc, NULL, &m_depthStencilBuffer);
    if (FAILED(result))
        return false;

    // Set up the description of the stencil state.
    depthStencilDesc.DepthEnable = true;
    depthStencilDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
    depthStencilDesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;

    depthStencilDesc.StencilEnable = true;
    depthStencilDesc.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
    depthStencilDesc.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;

    // Stencil operations if pixel is front-facing.
    depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
    depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

    // Stencil operations if pixel is back-facing.
    depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
    depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

    //create the depth stencil state
    result = m_device->CreateDepthStencilState(&depthStencilDesc, &m_depthStencil);

    //set the depth stencil state
    m_deviceContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(m_depthStencil, 1);

    //Set up the depth stencil view description
    depthStencilViewDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    depthStencilViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    depthStencilViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

    //Create the depth stencil view
    result = m_device->CreateDepthStencilView(m_depthStencilBuffer, &depthStencilViewDesc,&m_depthStencilView);
    if (FAILED(result))
        return false;

    //Bind the render target view and depth stencil buffer to the output render pipeline
    m_deviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_renderTarget, m_depthStencilView);

    //Setup the raster description which determines how and what polygons get drawn
    rasterDesc.AntialiasedLineEnable = false;
    rasterDesc.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_BACK;
    rasterDesc.DepthBias = 0;
    rasterDesc.DepthBiasClamp = 0.0f;
    rasterDesc.DepthClipEnable = true;
    rasterDesc.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_SOLID;
    rasterDesc.FrontCounterClockwise = false;
    rasterDesc.MultisampleEnable = false;
    rasterDesc.SlopeScaledDepthBias = 0.0f;

    //create the rasterizer state from the description
    result = m_device->CreateRasterizerState(&rasterDesc, &m_rasterState);

    // Now set the rasterizer state.
    m_deviceContext->RSSetState(m_rasterState);

    //Setup the viewport for rendering
    viewport.Width = (float)screenWidth;
    viewport.Height = (float)screenHeight;
    viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    viewport.TopLeftX = 0.0f;
    viewport.TopLeftY = 0.0f;

    // Create the view por
    m_deviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

    //set up the projection matrix
    fieldOfView = (float)D3DX_PI / 4.0f;
    screenAspect = (float)screenWidth / (float)screenHeight;

    //create the projection matrix for 3d rendering
    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&m_projectionMatrix, fieldOfView, screenAspect, screenNear, screenDepth);
```

Here is my code that renders the model(I made sure that all of the vertices where good)

```
float color[4];

    //set up the color to clear the buffer to
    color[0] = red;
    color[1] = green;
    color[2] = blue;
    color[3] = alpha;

    //clear the back buffer
    m_deviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(m_renderTarget, color);

    //clear the depth buffer
    m_deviceContext->ClearDepthStencilView(m_depthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f,0);

unsigned int stride;
    unsigned int offset;

    //set the vertex buffer stride and offset
    stride = sizeof(Vertex);
    offset = 0;

    //Set the vertex buffer to be active on the device context
    deviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &m_vertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);

    //Set the index buffer to active in the input assembler so it can be renderered
    deviceContext->IASetIndexBuffer(m_indexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);

    //set the type of primitive topology to use for rendering
    deviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

//Set the vertex input layout
    deviceContext->IASetInputLayout(m_layout);

    //Set the vertex and pixel shaders that will be used to render this triangle.
    deviceContext->VSSetShader(m_vertexShader, NULL, 0);
    deviceContext->PSSetShader(m_pixelShader, NULL, 0);

    //Set the sampler state in the pixel shader.
    deviceContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &m_sampleState);

    //Render the model
    deviceContext->DrawIndexed(indexCount, 0, 0);

//present the back buffer to the screen now that rendering is complete
    m_swapChain->Present(m_vsync, 0);
```

Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?(P.S I have the most recent version of this program in GitHub here : https://github.com/JustinWeq/Test-Engine . It has all of the files in it(including the model and the shader files, so if you need to look at it to get more information you can).

Comment: Posting a half billion lines of code and saying "something is wrong in here" is not helpful. Can you narrow this down to the section of code you think is non-functional, or the **minimal example** of something that's not working as expected?

Comment: One of the issues is I don't know what I could be doing wrong, I  have looked at all parameters and all the variables and they all seem to be working fine.I even copyed this code from a working example I had and it still did not work. IF someone could point me in the right direction then I could double check what I could be doing wrong. I would post a screen shot but I don't have 10 reputation yet. The back buffer is rendering(its green and the window background is red so I know that is working) but the cube is simply not rendering

Comment: This is not the shortest code necessary to reproduce your problem.  That creates the appearance that you are trying to save yourself some time at the cost of the time of everyone who might attempt to answer your question.

Comment: I agree, I have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out on my own.I only used this site as a very last resort, I post a lot of my code cause I truly do not know what I am doing wrong. If I did I would post a shorter block of code.

Comment: @JustinWeq it's clear you did your research and even commented the code, but the number of lines you've given us it too high to be reasonably helpful for anyone else. Can you cut stuff out that cannot possibly be interfering, and show us the rest? There's no way the few hundred lines of code are the absolute minimum you need to reproduce the issue. Alternatively, cut out a few lines, run it again, see if it works the same way, and move on to the next line.

Comment: I suggest you download the [Intel Graphics Performance Analyzers](https://software.intel.com/en-us/gpa) suit and find out what is wrong with your rendering pipeline.  
I don't suppose many us us are too eager to look through your wall of code for you.

Comment: @TankorSmash I removed the lines that checked for errors and left only the parameters of the descriptions of things. I hope that his makes my question easier to read.

Comment: @Beta Carotin Thanks I am downloading it now.

Comment: @JustinWeq the rest of the stuff is all necessary? That can't be right dude. Start from absolute scratch, and add only the lines that contribute to the error. If you don't know what a line does, don't add it. Only add it in if it reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was a few parameters I was missing when I was setting it up. I fixed it, thank you for trying to help me everyone.